# Can a child scene "slide" into a parent scene at runtime?

Tags: godot

Is it possible to "slide" a scene (type `Control`) into the middle of a scene at runtime.

I have a "parent" scene, with a blank area in the middle. I would like to "slide" a sequence of scenes into the central blank area of the parent scene.

I want to do something like this, but with animation:

```
var qi = load("res://Child1.tscn").instance()
qi.get_node("/root/Child1")
$VBoxContainer/MiddleArea.add_child(qi)
```

Then later on, slide in the same, or another type of scene, with different or the same data:

```
var qi = load("res://Child1.tscn").instance()
qi.get_node("/root/Child1")
$VBoxContainer/MiddleArea.add_child(qi)
```

The sequence is driven by data in a database, so its not predictable at design time what sequence of scenes might need to appear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, what you want can be done with a `Tween`.

So, first off all add `Tween` to the scene tree. We can hold it in a variable like this:

```
onready var tween := $Tween
```

Then we can use it to make a simple animation:

```
$VBoxContainer/MiddleArea.add_child(qi)

var duration_seconds := 2.0
tween.interpolate_property(
    qi,
    "rect_position",
    Vector2(-qi.rect_size.x, qi.rect_position.y),
    qi.rect_position,
    duration_seconds,
    Tween.TRANS_CUBIC,
    Tween.EASE_OUT
)
tween.start()
```

This code will animate the position of the scene. The starting position `Vector2(-qi.rect_size.x, qi.rect_position.y)` is just outside of the screen to the left. And the final position is wherever the scene is positioned before the animation.

If you are adding multiple in a loop at this line to await the end of the animation before doing the next one:

```
yield(tween, "tween_all_completed")
```

And if you are adding the scene to a container that is setting the position of the scene, you might want to add it like this:

```
qi.modulate = Color.transparent
$Container.add_child(qi)
yield(get_tree(), "idle_frame")
qi.self_modulate = Color.white
```

Here `qi.modulate = Color.transparent` will make the scene invisible. Then we add it to the container, and wait for one frame with `yield(get_tree(), "idle_frame")`, during which the container set the position of the scene. And finally we use `qi.self_modulate = Color.white` to restore the visibility. *We have to make the scene invisible so it does not appear for one frame just to disappear and then be animated. And we don't use `visible` because the container might skip positioning the scene.*